# Problem redirecting to another proxy, using Titanium.Web.Proxy in c#

Tags: c#, proxy, titanium-web-proxy

Yesterday, i started a very simple project with Titanium.Web.Proxy, for testing the libray. It consisted in redirecting all the requests to the proxy of my company, with my user and my pass. I got stucked here. I was able to recieve all the request from chrome(that's good!), but send them to the company's proxy... that's another story.
Even if it is a dirty solution, i tried to handle the request outside of the library to return the resulting byte array using SessionEventArgs.Respond, but failed. As said, that was a dirty solution, completly outside of the library.
So, my question is this one: How could I redirect the requests I receive to another proxy before going to internet, using Titanium.Web.Proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The example on the [github readme](https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/blob/develop/README.md#usage) has a (commented out) example of this:

```cs
proxyServer.UpStreamHttpProxy = new ExternalProxy() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 8888 };
proxyServer.UpStreamHttpsProxy = new ExternalProxy() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 8888 };
```

The ExternalProxy also has `Username` and `Password` properties, so I'd experiment with those too

Additional: You can also use `ExternalProxy.UseDefaultCredentials` to use the [`CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials?view=net-5.0), which is:

> An NetworkCredential that represents the network credentials of the current user or application.`

Comment: how can I put the AD domain?